# Adding Email Confirmation to Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed Michael Hartl's tutorial up to a point, then followed Ryan Bates' Railcast for adding reset password (#274).  Perhaps "tried to follow" is more accurate since I can't get the reset password to work despite many hours of effort/searching/tial&error.

Had to deviate from Ryan's call: @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) to: @user.update_attributes(user_params) as I was getting a ForbiddenAttributesError.

I also had to comment-out the #validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 } in the User class as it failed on submission (even though the submitted password was greater than 6 in length).

The code doesn't currently generate any errors, and the redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset!" works.  However, the password is not updated in the db.

Any insight is very gratefully received.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true, format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  #validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  before_create :create_remember_token

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private
    def generate_token(column)
      begin
        self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(40)
      end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
    end

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end

end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)        if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :password_reset_token)
    end

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions."
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
      redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password reset has expired."
    elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :password_digest, :remember_token, :admin, :auth_token, :password_reset_token, :password_reset_sent_at)
    end

end
```

app/views/password_resets/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Update Password" %></div>
<% end %>
```

app/views/password_resets/new.html.erb

```
<h1>PasswordReset#new</h1>

<%= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Reset Password" %></div>
<% end %>
```

There is no model for password_resets.

Comment: How do you verify password is not changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *app/views/password_resets/edit.html.erb*, your form describes `:password` and `:password_confirmation`. However, in your PasswordResetsController, you update using user_params, which describe `:id, :name, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :password_digest, :remember_token, :admin, :auth_token, :password_reset_token, :password_reset_sent_at`. Note the lack of the attributes you are trying to set. In the console, you will probably see a message indicating that the desired attributes have been discarded. Many of the attributes that you have added to user_params do not make sense in any context, as they would never be set by the user in any circumstance, like `:id, :created_at, :updated_at, :password_digest, :remember_token, :admin, :auth_token, :password_reset_token, :password_reset_sent_at`. In fact, may of these are blatant security risks (do you want the user to decide if they are an admin?). You will probably have better luck if you change the user_params method in PasswordResetsController to look like:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does make sense.  Very silly of me.  Thank you very much for taking the time to read the code and explain that.

Comment: @user2093191 Welcome to Stack Overflow! If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). That's the customary way of indicating that your question is "resolved" and thanking the person who helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the "welcome", Brad, in addition to the really useful answer.  I only just saw your last post.  I also just "accepted" it -- didn't realize I was supposed to do that -- duh!